# decompiler smart contract code, how to read the result?

Tags: fallback-function

i scanned the smart contract in the decompiler, how will the withdrawal function be translated?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reverse-engineering bytecode is not easy nor clean. In theory the reverse-engineered code is correct, but it's just very difficult to understand.

I'm not sure what tool you used - I've understood there are quite many alternatives. Some are for free and some not. You may want to try some other tool to at least be able to compare the results. Just be prepared that you probably won't get much better (easier to read) results with any tool.

Unfortunately I won't be able to tell you what that kind of code does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I try and compile the code, and load it with the at load address button in remix, how do I know it's the correct code?

Comment: In theory the resulted bytecode should be the same as the original, so you could just compare them. But my guess is that it will be a bit different, because the process is not perfect. But no idea really